# Chose to fight Blue at Battle Tree, how do I get Kanto Starter Mega Stones?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

In Pokemon Sun and Moon, once you enter the Battle Tree for the first time, you get challenged by Red and Blue, the "Champions" of Kanto. The Mega Stones for the Kanto starters are given by Red, but I chose to fight Blue at the Battle tree, who did not give me the Venusaurite, Charizardite X/Y, and Blastoisinite.

After choosing the trainer to fight, both trainers left and I did not receive the Mega Stones for Venusaur, Charizard, and Blastoise. Is there another chance for me to obtain the stones?

Comment: What's the point of spoilers in the body if you have a spoiler in the title?

Comment: I'd argue that the title isn't that much of a spoiler :c

Comment: But enough of a spoiler to put it in spoiler tags in the body, according to you. I'm just confused about the inconsistency.

Comment: I don't think beating him outside the tree even gets you the stones; I think you have to do it inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In regular singles you have to fight Red on the last battle (20) and then he will appear outside of the Battle Tree and give you the stones. **He doesn't give out stones on Super Singles.**

Answer (score 2):

According to [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/battletree.shtml), you are able to fight Red (and Blue, for that matter) in the Battle Tree randomly. They are listed as Special Trainers and you will fight one of them every 10 battles in Super Battles.

> In the Super Battles, these trainers will come every 10 wins in a streak and offer a bit of a challenge.

Since [defeating Red is what nets you the Venusaurite, Charizardite X/Y, and Blastoisite](http://www.nintendo-insider.com/2016/11/all-mega-stone-locations-in-pokemon-sun-and-moon/), it appears that regardless of whether or not you choose to defeat Red at the entrance of the Battle Tree, you will just have to beat him when he appears during your Battle Tree challenge as the last battle in Regular Singles, as mentioned in [Alexander's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/293956/162442).

Besides Red and Blue, you can also end up fighting Anabel, Colress, Cynthia, Dexio, Grimsley, Guzma, Kiawe, Mallow, Plumeria, Sina, or Wally.

Comment: I chose to fight Red when I first entered the Battle Tree, and he did not give me the megastones.

Answer (score -1):

I beat Red outside of Battle Tree and still didn't get the stones. I think you have to beat him in the official Battle Tree challenge to get the stones