# Can I get Mega Stones from Red for defeating him in Multis or does it have to be Singles?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Can I obtain the Mega Stones from defeating Red in the 20th Multi battle or do I have to defeat him in the 20th Single battle?

Comment: [Related, if not dupe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/293500/162442)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mega_Stone), you can get Venusaurite, Blastoisinite, Charizardite X, and Charizardite Y when defeated Red only in Single Battle Challenge.